# how to convert std::vector<vector> to void*

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am wondering how can I convert `std::vector<vector>` to `void*`, for example:

```
std::vector<ColorData> pixels_ (w*h, background_color);
```

Now I want to convert `pixels_` to `void*` so that I can `memcpy` the `pixels_`.

```
memcpy ((void*)destinationBuffer->pixels_, (void*)sourceBuffer->pixels_, \
sizeof(ColorData)*destinationBuffer->width_*destinationBuffer->height_);
```

But when I run this code, I get an error which says:

> invalid cast from type ‘std::vector<image_tools::ColorData>’ to type ‘void*’

How can I convert `std::vector<vector>` to `void*`?

Comment: Why not just copy the vector regularly?  Many implementations will call memcpy internally if it is a POD type.  This looks like a premature optimization to me.

Comment: ... or &*sourceBuffer.pixels.begin(), or &sourceBuffer.pixels.front().

Comment: In c++11 you have the `.data()` function to get a pointer to the underlying data. Otherwise you can do `&vec[0]`. But that is only if you really have to because usually there is a much better way (such as the mentioned std::copy).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To transform your vector into a `void*` type, there are two options:

- Pre C++11: `(void*)&pixels_[0]` (`!empty()` check is recommended)
- Since C++11: `static_cast<void*>(pixels_.data())`

However, if you want to copy the elements, go straight with STL functions:

- [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)
- [`std::uninitialized_copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/uninitialized_copy/)

They are type safe, your code looks much cleaner and the performance will be on par most of the times. Also, unlike `std::memcpy`, it also supports non-trivially copyable types (for example `std::shared_ptr`).

Remember:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%

See [TriviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable)

Update: since C++17 you can also use [`std::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data), which will work for any container using contiguous memory storage (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::array`).

```
ColorData* buffer = std::data(pixels_);
```

Comment: Excellent !  Worth to mention: the performance of the `std::copy()` will against all expectations be as good as, if not better than, `memcpy()`, at least for trivially copyable types.

Comment: Be aware that &piexls_[0] requires that you have a non-empty vector. The best is to check if there are any elements before copying. It seems that .data() avoids that (as well as using std::copy).

Comment: Thanks. For indexing that's right, although `operator[]` does not perform any bounds checking, its not a good practice to use it without doing the check. For `std::copy` is not necessary, as `begin()` will return a *past-the-end* iterator, so nothing will actually be copied.

Comment: @Christophe that's right. I can remember an specific case where using `std::copy<char*>` was faster than using `memcpy`, as the compiler (icc) was vectorizing the copy.

Comment: `static_cast<void*>` worked for me. Thanks!