# How to properly cast std::vector< std::vector<double> > to void* and reinterpret it back?

Tags: c++, nlopt

I am not an expert in c++ and I have a problem with casting a `std::vector< std::vector<double> > my_data` to a `void *f_data` and reinterpreting this cast.

Basically I need to convert `my_data`:

```
std::vector<double> point1(2);
point1[0] = 0.06; point1[1] = 2.07;
std::vector<double> point2(2);
point2[0] = 1.01; point2[1] = 0.02;
std::vector< std::vector<double> > my_data;
my_data.push_back(point1);
my_data.push_back(point2);
```

so that it fits the `opt.set_min_objective(vfunc vf, void *f_data)` function coming from the [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package in c++.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594494/how-to-convert-stdvectorvector-to-void), I am trying the following but it does not work:

```
auto *test = static_cast<void*>(my_data.data());
std::vector< std::vector<double> > *this_data = reinterpret_cast<std::vector< std::vector<double> >*>(test);
```

as I get the following error while debugging:

```
this_data=Cannot access memory at address 0x3faeb851eb851eb8
```

I have also tried this but it does not work either:

```
auto test = static_cast<void*>(my_data.data());
std::vector< std::vector<double> > *this_data = reinterpret_cast<std::vector< std::vector<double> >*>(test);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `(void*) &my_data`?

Comment: you can reinterpret_cast the data() of a vector to be a vector pointer. It isnt a vector, its the pointer to the inner data, minus all the control data. reinterpret_cast says 'trust me this is a pointer to a vector', it trusted you and broke. What are you trying to do

Comment: @Aplet123 the cast is redundant

Comment: It's perfectly understandable that you're not an "expert in C++" and you don't quite know how to do this. You should be happy to learn that actual C++ experts don't do anything of this sort, either, so you're in good company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup code would be:

```
opt.set_min_objective(vf, &my_data);
```

and then inside the vf function to retrieve a pointer to the original:

```
static_cast< std::vector<std::vector<double>>* >(f_data)
```

which you might like to use to initialize a reference:

```
auto& my_data = *static_cast< std::vector<std::vector<double>>* >(f_data);
```

Readability could be improved by a `using` declaration for the data type.